# Entries of matrix iterates

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices

We consider a matrix

$$A:=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & b & 0 &f \\a & 0 & e & 0 \\ 0 & d & 0 & h \\ c& 0 & g & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

This matrix has the interesting property that if you multiply it once with iself, it will have entries only where at the moment it has zero entries, in fact

$$A^2= \left(
\begin{matrix}
 a b+c f & 0 & b e+f g & 0 \\
 0 & a b+d e & 0 & a f+e h \\
 a d+c h & 0 & d e+g h & 0 \\
 0 & b c+d g & 0 & c f+g h \\
\end{matrix}
\right)$$

and by multiplying with $A$ again

$$A^3=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & b (a b+c f)+d (b e+f g) & 0 & f (a b+c f)+h (b e+f g) \\
 a (a b+d e)+c (a f+e h) & 0 & e (a b+d e)+g (a f+e h) & 0 \\
 0 & b (a d+c h)+d (d e+g h) & 0 & f (a d+c h)+h (d e+g h) \\
 a (b c+d g)+c (c f+g h) & 0 & e (b c+d g)+g (c f+g h) & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

the entries are back to where we started from.

I am wondering now, if there is a way to write an explicit (so not recursive) formula for the entries $A_{21}$ and $A_{41}$ of $A^{2n+1}$ and $n \in \mathbb N$?

Answer (score 1):

Swap the second and third row and column (which is a conjugation by the orthogonal permutation matrix
$$
\Pi = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 &0 & 0\\
0 & 0 &1 & 0\\
0 & 1 &0 & 0\\
0 & 0 &0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = \Pi^*.
$$
Then, working with $2\times 2$ blocks,
$$
\Pi A \Pi^* = \begin{bmatrix}0 & B\\ C & 0\end{bmatrix},
$$
with
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
b & f\\
d & h
\end{bmatrix}, \, C = \begin{bmatrix}a & e\\ c & g\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So
$$
\Pi A^{2n+1} \Pi^* = (\Pi A \Pi^*)^{2n+1} = ((\Pi A \Pi^*)^2)^n (\Pi A \Pi^*)= 
\begin{bmatrix}
BC & 0\\
0 & CB
\end{bmatrix}^n \begin{bmatrix}0 & B\\ C & 0\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}0 & (BC)^n B\\ (CB)^nC & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
If you expand out the entries of $CB$ and $BC$ in terms of $a,b,\dots,h$ you get closed formulas for all entries.